# How to mint multiple characters randomly?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, pallet-contracts, openbrush

Let me give scenario, let's say:
There are 2 types of playable characters

- Chickens (90% chance to mint)
- Foxes (10% chance to mint)

and total supply is 15,000 units :

- 13,500 chickens
- 1,500 foxes

**How to determine whether a Chicken or a Fox is minted?**

*I guess random number generator is good for this but random function is not supported anymore by ink!*

Comment: What do you mean? how to randomly pick one of the 2 options?

Comment: so total supply is 15,000 and We wan't mint function generate random number to determine whether a Chicken or a Fox is minted. @AlexBean

Answer (score 1):

Generate the random number between 1 and 15,000 based on a future block hash then if the random number is in the first 10% of values in that range then you could determine that a Chicken was minted, whereas if the random number is in the remaining 90% of that range then you could determine that a Fox was minted.

Comment: how to get `block_hash` in ink! smart contract @Luke Schoen? There is not function to get block has [here](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_env/index.html#functions)

Comment: i've highlight the only solution i can think of for ink! that should work at the moment here https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/1849#issuecomment-1641098345, which involves having your ink! contract perform a cross-contract call to a Solidity contract that simply returns the relevant block hash since that function is supported in Solidity, for example run `blockhash(blockNumber - 1);` to get the previous block hash with Solidity. but that would only work on a chain that supports both Wasm and EVM contracts like Astar, since whilst cross-contract calls are supported.

Comment: i've already written some code to generate a random number between 1 and 20 based on a future block hash here in 'rand-future' example https://github.com/ltfschoen/XCMTemplate/pull/23/files#diff-8204ef18b173711414617cb0ab5680e976995169b27ba1767fac9589fa950f30R87, but i'm manually providing the block hash as argument `block_hash_entropy` to function `set_block_for_entropy_for_market_id`, to generate the random number for a guessing game that started earlier. next step is for that ink! contract to perform a cross-contract call to a Solidity contract that simply returns the current block hash

Comment: also see https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/9325/83

Comment: FYI, here's my PR that uses cross-contact XVM to call from ink! to Solidity to get the block hash https://github.com/ltfschoen/XCMTemplate/pull/24/files#diff-98af389605118659c220cd8a1f601f2550ba2b6801dee17dfe6b0edcf5ef73a7R4