# Generate random number ink!

Tags: ink, smart-contract, substrate-contracts-node

I am writing ink! contract to generate random number between min and max value. I found [this](https://docs.astar.network/docs/build/builder-guides/xvm_wasm/pseudo_random/) article. Here we can generate random number between 0 to 99. Then I modified to generate random number between 0 to 14999. But I am testing for long time I never get value more than 252. Is there something wrong with this code? Someone please check this code. It is possible to generate random number between 0 to 14999 using this code or not?

Here is my code repo [github](https://github.com/ganesh1233456/random-ink)

Comment: What specifically are you going to use the random number for?

Comment: For [this](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/q/9286/2844) @LukeSchoen

Comment: and I am following [as you mentioned here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/9310/2844)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Keccak256 hash algorithm produces a 256-bit (32-byte) hash, and its associated type `Type` is `[u8; 32]`.

In your code you always take just `output[0]` of type `u8` and your result is always less than `u8::MAX`, which is `255u8` as mentioned [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/u8/constant.MAX.html).
To use more bits from the generated hash you can change your code to something like:

```rust
let number_bytes = [output[0], output[1]];
let z = u16::from_be_bytes(number_bytes);
let number = z as u128 % (self.max_value + 1);
```